# updating a field where field cannot be less than zero

Tags: ms-access-2007

im using the following query to update my field

UPDATE tableName SET fieldName = fieldName-10
WHERE id=1;

and this is working fine in my case but i want that if the result is less than zero than query should not execute.

i've tried this
UPDATE tableName SET fieldname = fieldName-10
WHERE id=1 and fieldName>0;

but it returns with an error syntax error in your UPDATE statement.

thanx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you mean this? if pqty is the field of your table.

```
UPDATE tableName SET fieldname = pqty-10 WHERE id=1 and pqty>10;
```

Comment: and sorry i edited most of my query to make it understandable.. but i didnot notice that pqty is the same as i wrote in my query..